# Derivative of exponential functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, exponential-function

I'm having trouble for the derivative of this exponential function which looks difficult. I have used the quotient rule and chain rule to solve for $0.6^x$ but its still wrong.

$$P(x)= \frac{1864}{1+49\times (0.6)^x}$$

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: $$P'(x)=-\frac{1864\times\frac{d}{dx}\left(1+49\times(0.6)^x\right)}{(1+49\times(0.6)^x)^2}=\\=-\frac{1864\times49\times\ln(0.6)\times(0.6)^x}{(1+49\times(0.6)^x)^2}$$

Comment: use the representation $0.6^x=e^{ln(0.6)x}$

Comment: Thank you Sassatelli, I understand it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have after simplifications $$P'(x)=-91336\,{\frac { \left( 3/5 \right) ^{x}\ln  \left( 3/5 \right) }{
 \left( 1+49\, \left( 3/5 \right) ^{x} \right) ^{2}}}
$$